# How do I "inset" one image into another image in Inkscape?

Tags: inkscape, logo, svg, images, merge

I'm trying to create a custom happy birthday logo for laser engraving that incorporates the happy birthday vector image and the cancer ribbon vector image that I have created (attached). I am trying to recreate the effect seen in the Home is where the heart is screenshot that I have attached using Inkscape. Essentially I want to "trim" the cancer ribbon so that the upper and lower portions fit around the happy birthday logo. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image][image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure the ribbon graphic is a compound path, and the text (and crown) is another compound path above the ribbon path. If everything is different paths, you may have to select some of them and make them a compound path using *Path > Combine*.

Anyway, after you have your two compound paths set up . . .

1. Duplicate the text path using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>.  Add an Offset path effect to it, using *Path > Path Effects*, hit the plus button in the Path Effects panel, and search and choose the Offset Path LPE

[image]

2. With the Edit Paths by Nodes tool, move the offset control to thicken up the text. Then do *Path > Object to Path* to bake in the path effect

[image]

3. Select both the top text path and the ribbon path and do *Path > Difference*. This is a boolean operation which will cut out a hole in the ribbon.

Finished example, showing outlines (right)

[image]